# How to get the child of a SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I intend to get the WebView child inside a given SwipeRefreshLayout. The child was added via `addView()` method:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.addView(webView);
```

This is supposed to be very simple. Since I have to to retrieve the webview back, I have to cast it:

```
(WebView) swipeRefreshLayout.getChildAt(0);
```

However, this gives me an exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: b.t.b.a cannot be cast to android.webkit.WebView
```

I also tried casting the Layout to ViewGroup but android studio mentioned its redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child at Index 0 is the **CircleImageView** and the second child is the **View** that you added inside it in The xml file.Please try with :

```
  int childCount = swipeRefreshLayout.getChildCount();
        WebView webView;
        for (int i =0 ;i<childCount;i++){ 
            if (swipeRefreshLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof  WebView){
                webView = (WebView) swipeRefreshLayout.getChildAt(i);
            }
        }

 // here you can use your WebView
```

Or you can just use

```
swipeRefreshLayout.getChildAt(1)
```

Comment: if you add a `Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+swipeRefreshLayout.getChildAt(i) );` you notice that the swipeRefreshLayout is composed of 2 view the first is the progressView(CircleImageView) that you see when swipe the swipeRefreshLayout and the Second view is your WebView

Comment: this one also works: `(WebView) swipeRefreshLayout.getChildAt(1);`

Comment: yes i used the loop for for more clearty because it contains several views

Comment: Your answer is more accurate. Tnx mate!

Comment: I think for a view does not change the number of childs you can directly use getChildAt (1) like swipRef. but for a ViewGroup which can change the number of childs dynamically the safest way is to use the for loop